# How do I refernce a DOM element by ID using a variable in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, dom

If I have several divs in my HTML like this

```
<div id="div_1"></div>
<div id="div_2"></div>
<div id="div_3"></div>
```

In my JavaScript, how can I reference them using a variable?

```
// Using Jquery to assign the element to the variable name
$div_1 = $(div_1);
$div_2 = $(div_2);
$div_3 = $(div_3);

// set the CSS for each div
for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
  $div_[i].css({'left': 100 +'px'});   
}
```

Comment: `$('[id^=div]').css('left', '100px')`

Comment: `{'left'}` at `.css({'left'}: 100 +'px'});` is invalid syntax for first parameter to `.css()`. First parameter should be a string, not an object.

Answer (score 1):

ID's are just strings, so build them as such:

```
id = 2;

e = document.getElementById('div_' + id);
```

If you mean store each of the found elements, then you need an array:

```
divs = [];
divs[1] = $('#div_1');
divs[2] = $('#div_2');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create variable holding all elements, use `.filter()` to select an element having a specific full `id`, or `id` ending with specific digit or letter characters

```
// all `div` elements having `id` beginning with `"div"`
var divs = $("div[id^=div]");
// select element having `id` ending with `"2"`:`"div_2"` from `divs` collection
var div_2 = divs.filter("[id$=2]");
```

Comment: You have a minor typo, you're missing the `=`: `$("div[id^div]")` should be: `$("div[id^=div]")`.

Comment: so essentially it becomes an array?

Comment: @user2721815 `jQuery()` returns an "array-like" object. You could also store elements in an actual array. As indicated by @adeneo, chaining `.css()` to the collection should set properties for all elements in collection.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the "id" attribute of your divs and obtain a reference like below:

```
$div_1 = $("#div_1");
```